# Run ASP.NET Core app with HTTPS from Visual Studio for private network address

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, ssl, asp.net-core-mvc, ssl-certificate

I'm developing ASP.NET Core MVC web app (.NET 5) with allowing HTTPS. The main goal is to get a web app with SignalR support with other devices to send/receive messages with a bit of security using HTTPS.

In project properties -> Debug tab -> Web Server Settings -> Enable SSL is checked.

In project-name/.vs/project-name/config/applicationhost.config file I have these bindings in web app's site node:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44903:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44367:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44367:127.0.0.1" /><!-- added by me -->
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44367:10.128.0.75" /><!-- added by me -->
```

When I run the web app using visual studio https://localhost:44367 is opened with lock icon in browser's address bar. If I open https://127.0.0.1:44367 or https://10.128.0.75:44367, the web site is opened, but with warning icon and "not secure" message in address bar.

Using SignalR client in the same machine, I can connect to https://localhost:44367/hub. If I try to connect with SignalR to https://127.0.0.1:44367/hub or https://10.128.0.75:44367/hub client I get this exception:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

Inner exception:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

How can I solve this problem, even if it is to be able to use the 10.128.0.75 address?

Comment: Why don't you want to use localhost?

Comment: Because I want to test SignalR with an android device (SignalR client) and need to access to web server. So I need to use private network IP address.

Comment: In this case you'd need to use a certificate that was installed and trusted on the android device. Instead of going through this pain, it's easier to use ngrok or similar to tunnel through a public address into your localhost dev endpoint.

Comment: I'm going to try ngrok, but I don't know if this will solve the certificate problem.

Comment: nrgok has a cert signed by a public CA, so it should work out of the box on any device